# Help me identify this insect found in fishtank

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

This bug appeared in my fish tank,transparent 6 legged with 3 tail insect. Anyone able to identfy this, please help. Many thanks

Comment: Please add some more images, including a better close-up, some morphological details, your location, etc.

Answer (score 10):

This is a **Damselfly**, suborder *Zygoptera*. Together with the *Anisoptera* (true dragonflies) they belong to the order *Odonata*, usually also named dragonflies.

Damselflies are smaller and more slender then Dragonflies, both as larva and as adult, although there are exceptions (mostly tropical species).

It can be distinguished from mayflies by it's broad head and the broad, flat lamellae; the 3 'tails' as you call them.

Some beautiful pictures can be found [here](http://lifeinfreshwater.net/damselfly-nymphs-odonata-zygoptera/)